# PHP INNER JOIN two tables ID matching issue

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

On my project I want to execute this code to get a certain result:

```
$abc = "SELECT * 
  FROM ptc_ads 
  INNER JOIN ptc_ads_viewed 
    ON ptc_ads.pads_id = ptc_ads_viewed.padv_id 
  WHERE ptc_ads.pads_id != ptc_ads_viewed.padv_ad_id 
    OR ptc_ads_viewed.padv_uname != '".$uname."' 
    AND ptc_ads.pads_group = '1' 
    AND ptc_ads.pads_mem1 = '1' 
  ORDER BY ptc_ads.pads_id DESC";

$res = mysql_query($abc) or die(mysql_error());
```

I think the problem is that the fields which I have used to join should have equal data.

If `ptc_ads.pads_id` is 1,2,3,4 then `ptc_ads_viewed.padv_id` should also be 1,2,3,4. But in my case its not possible to have same rows.

In `ptc_ads_viewed.padv_id` there are more rows than `ptc_ads_viewed.pads_id` so the fields do not match and is returning the result only where both rows matche.

For example: `ptc_ads_viewed.pads_id` contains two rows so it has two id's (1,2) and `ptc_ads_viewed.padv_id` has four id's (1,2,3,4). So the query is returning the result only for the first two ids of both the tables (1,2). And 3,4 is left untouched. But expected result is also in 3,4. Is there anyway how I can get result from all the rows in `ptc_ads_viewed.padv_id`?

Comment: The judicious use of parentheses may prove advantageous

Comment: can you please elaborate? use of an example code will be helpful.

Comment: E.g.: (3 x 5) + 4 = 19 but 3 x (5 + 4) = 27. Can you see how that relates to your issue?

Comment: you have an sql injection vulnerability. you might want to escape $uname

Comment: Using RIGHT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN would give you all rows that fulfill the condition plus the rows from ptc_ads_viewed that dont have a match in ptc_ads with the ptc_ads part of the result populated with NULLs/default values. (Or the other way round with LEFT JOIN, I think your example is a bit inconsistent on table names.) But that wont work here because your conditions refer to both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `INNER JOIN` - this means that you will get results that exists on both tables, so in your example, you'll get only 1 and 2

You can use left or right join, that way you'll get the all results (left join means - rows that exist on the first table but not in the second- you will get the data from the first table, and for the second table's columns you'll get nulls)